# Зачем точка в JavaScript Ex: value.countReload = 1;

Tags: javascript

Недавно видел в примерах JS точку, но никак не могу понять зачем она, ли то для изменения переменных внутри функций из вне, или еще чего, прошу извинения за свою некомпетентность, и возможно глупый вопрос.
Пример:
value.countReload = 1

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Это обращения к свойству обьекта   .Value это обьект а countReload его свойство

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точка это обращение к свойству объекта.

```
A = { id:1, age: {day: 2, month:5}}

var Day = A.age.day;
```

Comment: Интересно, что неверного в ответе?

Comment: Нельзя задавать свойства для свойств.

Comment: @TheErehteyon Попробуйте вставить в devtool Chrome скрипт из моего ответа и убидитесь, что можно.